# How can convert integer to datetime in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe as below:

| id | dateTime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1639072451000 |
| 2 | 1639037429000 |
| 3 | 1639060736000 |

If I write the code below:

```
 df['dateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateTime'])
```

The result is like this:
| id | dateTime |
|----| ---------|
|1   |1/1/1970  12:27:19 AM|
|2   |1/1/1970  12:27:19 AM|
|3   |1/1/1970  12:27:19 AM|

while the correct dateTime for `id = 1` is `12/9/2021  5:54:11 PM`.
Also I have tried this code as well:

```
df['dateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateTime'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

But I faced this error:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError X
time data '1639072451000' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p' (match)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unit='ms'`:

```
df['dateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateTime'], unit='ms')
print (df)
   id            dateTime
0   1 2021-12-09 17:54:11
1   2 2021-12-09 08:10:29
2   3 2021-12-09 14:38:56
```